# Using a date range in an where class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**1. Context**

For a reservation form, I'm trying to get all the unavailable rooms for the selected dates.

I am able to get all the rooms that have reservations via:

```
@unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel})
```

```
=> [#<Room:0x00007f8787daadc0 id: 6, name: "1", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787da8228 id: 7, name: "2", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787da2698 id: 7, name: "2", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787da15b8 id: 6, name: "1", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787da0398 id: 6, name: "1", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787d9acb8 id: 7, name: "2", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787d98e90 id: 6, name: "1", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787d930d0 id: 7, name: "2", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>]
```

**2. Issue**

The issue is that I'am not able to get all the @unavailable_rooms for a time range. I try it with this line of code:

```
@unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? < reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct
```

**3. Example case:**

- for a new reservation I fill in the arrival:`2019/11/24` and departure: `2019/11/26`
- room 1 is already booked for arrival:`2019/11/24` and departure `2019/11/25`
- room 2 is already booked for arrival: `2019/11/25` and departue: `2019/11/26`

=> @unavailable_rooms should return

```
#<Room:0x00007f8787daadc0 id: 6, name: "1", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Room:0x00007f8787da8228 id: 7, name: "2", room_category_id: 4, created_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 16:21:16 UTC +00:00>]
```

but currently only returns:

```
[]
```

**4. Code**

hotels_controller

```
def rooms_availability
  hotel = Hotel.includes(:rooms).find(params[:id])
  arrival = Date.parse room_params[:arrival]
  departure = Date.parse room_params[:departure]
  time_span = arrival..departure
  @unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? < reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct
  hotel_cats = hotel.room_categories
  hotel_accos = Room.where(room_category: hotel_cats)
  @rooms = hotel_accos - @unavailable_rooms
  authorize @rooms
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_category
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_category
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :room_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_categories
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class RoomCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`room1`:

- `2019/11/24` is less or equal than `2019/11/24`
- `2019/11/26` isn't less than `2019/11/25`.
- Hence room1 won't match with the query given.

`room2`:

- `2019/11/24` isn't less or equal than `2019/11/25`
- `2019/11/26` isn't less than `2019/11/26` (is the same).
- Hence room2 won't match with the query given.

There's no problem in the code. There are no records for the filter you applied.